# Plotly Geoscatter with Aggregation: show aggregation in hover Info

Tags: python, plotly

I have been trying to create a Geoscatter Plot with Plotly where the marker size should indicate the number of customers (row items) in one city (`zip_city`). I based my code on two templates from the Plotly documentation: [United States Bubble Map](https://plot.ly/python/bubble-maps/) and the aggregation part [Mapping with Aggregates](https://plot.ly/python/aggregations/).

I managed to put together a code that does what I want, except for one drawback: when I hover over a bubble, I would like to see the name of the city plus number of customers (the result from the aggregation), so something like *Aguadilla: 2*. Can you help me on how to do this?

Here is my code (as a beginner with plotly, I am also open to code improvements):

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Customer': [111, 222, 555, 666],
        'zip_city': ['Aguadilla', 'Aguadilla', 'Arecibo', 'Wrangell'],
        'zip_latitude':[18.498987, 18.498987, 18.449732,56.409507],
        'zip_longitude':[-67.13699,-67.13699,-66.69879,-132.33822]})

data = [dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = df['zip_longitude'],
        lat = df['zip_latitude'],
        text = df['Customer'],
        marker = dict(
            size = df['Customer'],
            line = dict(width=0.5, color='rgb(40,40,40)'),
            sizemode = 'area'
            ),
        transforms = [dict(
                            type = 'aggregate',
                            groups = df['zip_city'],
                            aggregations = [dict(target = df['Customer'], func = 'count', enabled = True)]
                            )]
        )]


layout = dict(title = 'Customers per US City')

fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
pyo.plot( fig, validate=False)
```

### Update:

Can I access the result of the `transforms` argument directly in the `data` argument to show the number of customers per city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list, that will contains what you want and then set `text=list` in `data`. Also do not forget specify `hoverinfo='text'`.

I am updated your code, so try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as pyo

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Customer': [111, 222, 555, 666],
        'zip_city': ['Aguadilla', 'Aguadilla', 'Arecibo', 'Wrangell'],
        'zip_latitude':[18.498987, 18.498987, 18.449732,56.409507],
        'zip_longitude':[-67.13699,-67.13699,-66.69879,-132.33822]})

customer = df['Customer'].tolist()
zipcity = df['zip_city'].tolist()
list = []
for i in range(len(customer)):
    k = str(zipcity[i]) + ':' + str(customer[i])
    list.append(k)

data = [dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = df['zip_longitude'],
        lat = df['zip_latitude'],
        text = list,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        marker = dict(
            size = df['Customer'],
            line = dict(width=0.5, color='rgb(40,40,40)'),
            sizemode = 'area'
            ),
        transforms = [dict(
                            type = 'aggregate',
                            groups = df['zip_city'],
                            aggregations = [dict(target = df['Customer'], func = 'count', enabled = True)]
                            )]
        )]

layout = dict(title = 'Customers per US City')

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig, validate=False)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response! Sorry I did not have the time until now to answer. What I was looking for was the number of customers per city (result of the aggregation) in the hoverinfo, not the customer number per se. However your solution directed me to the following workaround: add an aggregated column to the dataframe (customers per city) and use this column in the list you proposed, which gives what I wanted. Is it not possible to access the result of `transforms` directly in the `data` statement without the extra step of grouping and a list?

Comment: @PatrickGlettig Im tried, but dont succeeded now. In `data` I can not nothing to do with `transforms`. So extra step needed as I think